# activate an application when a power button is clicked

Tags: android

i want to create such application in android which will be activated when i press sleep or power button twice  , is it possible to do that , by running an application in background and listening events from power button ?

some times phone gets into sleep mode once it is idle , and to use any application user has to press
sleep button and then he has to enter certain password to activate the phone. But i want to make make it activate my application when a power button is clicked without any other intervention

Comment: you have to write a service to do that, I didn't try it but, here is a smiliar question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907102/home-button-listener

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this trick .

Register a Broadcast Receiver which is initiated when powerbutton is clicked.
Now in OnReceive method of the Receiver do what you want.

For example:

in manifest file register a receiver:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.test.check.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

&& in onReceive() method of the Receiver

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Log.v("#@%@%#", "Power button is pressed.");  

         Toast.makeText(arg0, "power button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //perform what you want here
    }
}
```

Now perform any operation in onReceive() method of the Receiver.

Comment: Hey the above tricked worked .... I did this code and its working and shows the toast when power button is connected or disconnected .. I modified the code a bit , so I am editing the above post a bit.. hope it can help you ...

Comment: Can you please tell what changes you have made in the above code. and please paste a full code of menifiest file. thanks

Comment: from this 5 actions the only one working while telefone is locked is the SCREEN_ON-Event.

Comment: @DineshSharma It is not working for me. I have created a broadcast reciever extended class and added above code in Manifest file. What am I missing?

Comment: @Dinesh Sharma This Broadcast Receiver will work for power connected or DISCONNECTED (power cable)not for power button press event.

Answer (score 0):

this is an key down event of power you can get some idea from this just try on this you'll get some idea...
i didnt try such an act but i found this in power manager.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // do what you want with the power button
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This only works if activity where _onKeyDown_ is running and active