# Listen power key press when device's keyguard locked

Tags: android, service, android-service

Assuming a service is running in background for three to four hours. In that particular time:

When Android device's keyguard is in locked state, I want to listen to an event, for example a power key press three times subsequently, and open an activity that will be a pattern lock.

#### Summary

1. Start a service for 3 - 4 hours.
2. Keyguard Lock.
3. Press power button 3 times subsequently.
4. Open Lock pattern as an activity.

How to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941006/1056359) about hooking the power button with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

all you need to add is the counter and make the Activity with the lock pattern. (try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864345/1056359))