# double press power button start activity of app

Tags: android, button, sms, location

I'm making an app which sends the location when the button is pressed.Its working fine with button on layout,but i want to do that part with DOUBLE press power button.
Please suggest me the way to do.
And also how to use power button double press.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292376/how-to-start-the-app-on-power-button-press?rq=1  this link may give you some idea

Comment: i tried this but it gives Fatal Error and app got crashed.

Comment: @Yushi have you done with this? i am in same boat ...

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do the exact same thing: start the application main function when double pressing the power button.
Have you found a solution ?

EDIT:
There's a solution in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android).

I don't find interesting of sending back information to the service: I start the activity directly in the receiver.
That works well ... at least for me ! ! ;-)

Comment: Every thing is in the post given in the anwser above.