# Press Power button to launch application

Tags: android

I found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292376/how-to-start-the-app-on-power-button-press) to launch application by doing press on Power button.

And i don't know why this code not working for me, but anyways i am placing some code with manifest, please check ...

and tell me **is it the right code to launch an app by single or twice press of Power button?**

```
   toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    btnToggleLock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (btnToggleLock.isChecked()) {    

                    toast.cancel();
                    toast.setText("Unlocked");
                    toast.show();

                    Log.i("Unlocked", "If");

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    KeyguardManager _guard = (KeyguardManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    KeyguardLock _keyguardLock = _guard
                            .newKeyguardLock("KeyguardLockWrapper");
                    _keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();

                    PanicButtonActivity.this.startService(new Intent(
                            PanicButtonActivity.this, UpdateService.class));

                } else {

                    toast.cancel();
                    toast.setText("Locked");
                    toast.show();

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    KeyguardManager _guard = (KeyguardManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    KeyguardLock _keyguardLock = _guard
                            .newKeyguardLock("KeyguardLockWrapper");
                    _keyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();

                    Log.i("Locked", "else");

                    PanicButtonActivity.this.stopService(new Intent(PanicButtonActivity.this,
                            UpdateService.class));

                }

            }
        });
```

**Receiver.java:**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    mReceiver = new Receiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    Log.i("onDestroy Reciever", "Called");

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
    if (!screenOn) {
        Log.i("screenON", "Called");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Awake", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        Log.i("screenOFF", "Called");
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

**Manifest.xml:-**

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.panic.app.PanicButtonActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.panic.app.Receiver" />
    <service android:name="com.panic.app.UpdateService" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, unlike other broad casted intentsso You need to make a service which will keep on running like this :

```
public static class UpdateService extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new Receiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
            if (!screenOn) {
                // your code
            } else {
                // your code
            }
        }
}
```

and your receiver can be something

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```