# Detect double press power button in android background service

Tags: android, service

I have to trigger back in my application through simplest user interaction with phone, for example pressing power button 3 times. Is there any way that I could listen to power button events in service ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to start the app on power button press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292376/how-to-start-the-app-on-power-button-press)

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the power key event by following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER == event.getKeyCode()){
      if(time interval is less)//Consider as double click
       //code to do on power press
        else            //Consider as single click
       //nothing to do   
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Well, this would have worked if it have to be done in activity, in my case, I have to catch it in background service. Thanks anyways