# How to handle events from Android power button

Tags: android

I want to handle the button on the edge of the upper right side of the device. The one that turns the screen on and off.

What is the name of that button and how do I handle events from it?

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button) as the answer is full and thorough there.

Comment: There are few tips and tricks you can found on SO like this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941006/209574